# Store third party services login/password in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, .net-core

My .NET Core application requires connections to a number of third party services.
Some of these services use login/password credentials, and this is a problem.

Application is cross-platform (Windows/Linux) and "cross-database" one (out of the box it works with MS SQL and PostgreSQL, and this can be extended). In fact, it's a Windows service, when working in Windows, and a daemon, when working in Linux.

For scalability purposes it's OK to run several application instances. Because of this, application settings, including credentials, are stored in database.

The question is how to avoid storing passwords as clear text.

I can't use any platform-specific solutions like [`ProtectedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netframework-4.7.2) or Credential Manager. I can't store hashed passwords as well, because they will be validated by third-party services. Theoretically, I can use some db-specific code to encrypt/decrypt passwords, if database servers have such ability.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will not be able to do so as the third party services would need to change their implementations - maybe you could use asymmetric encryption? You will encrypt the password with public key of particular party and store it that way in DB. Each party will decrypt it and then check credentials.

However as I said, probably you can't do it that way :) but I am now aware of any "cross-database" encryption

Other way - maybe store password in environment variable? (both windows and linux supports it)

Comment: Third party services can't be changed. Both SQL Server and PostgreSQL have options to encrypt/decrypt particular column. This is one of the way I will try. Second option is to encrypt storage, where DB is located. Both not as easy and ideal. Maybe I'm missing something and there is a way out-of-the box in .net core.

Comment: I was thinking ahead of yet another DB which may be used in future? With the asp.net core except the environment variables i have only heard/read about the secret manager which I suppose is fully windows dependent and (probably?) is only recommended while development. Sorry I couldn't help! but still I am curious which approach(maybe one not mentioned here?) will you finally choose as the problem is quite not easily solvable and each approach have its pros and cons